# Spell Checker for TFS Work Items

Tags: tfs, spell-checking

I want to be able to check my spelling (and grammar) when I am entering text into work item fields (for example a PBI or Bug) in TFS VS2010. I found [this addon](http://witspellchecker.codeplex.com/) and installed it.  Is there anything else should I do besides run the installer?  I can not find any spell checking buttons when I am inputting work items.

Any idea why this is happening?

What is wrong with the installation?

Is there any better way to add spell checking capability to work items in TFS?

Answer (score 3):

After Installing the Custom Control you still need to manualy add the custom control to you work item definition.

Best way to do this is using the Process Editor from TFS Power Tools: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Adam

Comment: I have this plugin but seems like not working when you open a work item from Visual Studio 2015 (works for CS files and etc..) I have checked the global settings file as well for the spell checker under tools